# C++ caesar cipher — understanding ascii keys

Tags: c++

I am currently doing a caesar cipher program. It should encrypt for both lower and upper case.

e.g
If I typed in a, it will then shift the keys by 3 and the final output will become d.

Take a look at my codes

```
char c;
c = (((97-52)+3) % 26) + 52;
cout << c;
```

The letter 'a' has an ASCII code of 97.

So by right

```
1) ((97-52)+3) will give you 48

2) 48 % 26 will give you 8 since 48/26 will give you a remainder of 8.

3) 8 + 52 = 60(which will by right give you a value of '>' according to the ascii table)
```

but my output that I have got is J and I don't understand which am I getting the output of 'J' instead of '>'

My concepts might be wrong so I need help.

Comment: 48 % 26 is actually 22.

Comment: If you just want to right shift characters by 3, why all the extra operations. Can you explain why not just add 3?

Comment: @remyabel may I know why 48 % 26 = 22?

Comment: @Miguel because shifting z by 3 will give you bogus

Comment: @user2935569 26 * 2 = 52 not 42

Comment: In writing your code, it would probably be easier to read (and for us to help debug) if you used character literals instead of numeric constants. I.e. `'A'` instead of `97`, etc.

Comment: Ok, I would just use a different approach that's all. for example if it's greater than the maximum number just circle back to the first number. But hey, there are many ways to skin a cat.

Comment: @Novelocrat: Using 'A' for 97 would confuse; 'A' normally has the code 65; 'a' has the code 97.

Answer (score 0):

Let me link ASCII chart I use first: http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII
The website is polish, but table itself is in english.

I think it's plainly obvious that problem is the equatation you use:

```
(((letter-52)+3) % 26) + 52;
```

**Actually first letter in ASCII is `65`**(hexadecimal `0x41` - follow with the chart provided).
Your idea with the modulo would be fine, if there were no chars between letter blocks in ASCII. But there are (again check up chart).

That is why you should manually check if the sign:

1. is a capital letter: `if (letter >= 0x41 && letter <= 0x5a)`
2. is a non-capital: `if (letter >= 0x61 && letter <= 0x7a)`

Usually when making Ceasar cipher, you should follow these:

1. Replace a capital letter with capital letter moved in the alphabet by a given number.
2. If the letter would be out of alphabet scope, continue iteration from the start of alphabet (X moved 5 to the right would give C).
3. Other chars stay the same

Now let's implement this (in code I'll use letter values of chars - to avoid mistakes):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

string Ceasar(string input, int offset)
{
    string result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i)
    {
        // For capital letters
        if (input[i] >= 'A' && input[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            result += (char) (input[i] - 'A' + offset) % ('Z' - 'A') + 'A';
            continue;
        }

        // For non-capital
        if (input[i] >= 'a' && input[i] <= 'z')
        {
            result += (char) (input[i] - 'a' + offset) % ('z' - 'a') + 'a';
            continue;
        }

        // For others
        result += input[i];
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    cout << Ceasar(string("This is EXamPLE teXt!?"), 8).c_str();
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Your code is very much on the right track.  However, note that `'Z' - 'A'` is 25, not 26.  Frankly, I think it would be as clear to use 26 as `'Z' - 'A' + 1`.  It would also be reasonable to use `isupper()` and `islower()` to identify letters of each case, though the range comparisons work with ASCII.  I'd also write the code to avoid using `continue`: probably use `char c;` and assign it in three alternatives of an `if / else if / else` chain and then finish the loop body with `result += c;`.